# How to print this after searching those string in a file using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I can search these values but i an stuck how to print in the format while executing this file log.txt

```
Dlog = 0
MeanDlog = 102
i_min = 22 


Dlog = 10
MeanDlog = 10
i_min = 20
```

I have file.txt that has these lines over and over many times but its value changes ,I need to save these like this

In a print like these after the execution of that file

```
Dlog = {0, 10} 
MeanDlog = {102,10}
i_min = {22,20}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you:

```
variables = dict() #Create a dictionary to store the split lines

with open("input.txt") as i_file: #Open the file
    for line in i_file:
        if line == "\n" or line.find("=") == -1: #Skip blank lines and lines with no equals sign
            continue
        name, value = line.strip("\n").split(" = ") #Split lines into two parts based on the "=" sign

        if name not in variables:
            variables[name] = list()

        variables[name].append(int(value))

with open("output.txt", "w") as o_file: #Can be changed to whatever file you want to write to
    for item in variables:
        temp = str(variables[item])
        temp = temp.replace("[","{").replace("]","}").replace(" ", "")
        o_file.write(item + " = " + temp +"\n")
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code.py", line 7, in <module>
    name, value = line.strip("\n").split(" = ") #Split lines into two parts base
d on the "=" sign
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack